# How to "Show Changes" function in Excel Online using office js APIs?

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

I have developed an javascript excel online add-in. where I have requirement to fetch a list of all change logs

I have seen that the `Show Changes` button is available in Excel Online

Is there a way to fetch this data using Excel Office APIs?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but no, there aren't any APIs in the Office JavaScript library for accessing this information. You can request that Microsoft create such an API at  [M365 Development Platform Ideas](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform).